# Where does intellij idea store binary, source and javadoc jar files?

Tags: intellij-idea

When importing a maven folder into intellij, I check these options:

[image]

But after indexing and downloading and other busy activities shown in the status bar, I still can't find binary, source or javadoc jar files:

```
tree .
.
├── funFx.iml
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── java
    │       └── vu
    │           └── co
    │               └── kspace
    │                   ├── App.java
    │                   ├── Digits.java
    │                   ├── ISBN10.java
    │                   └── Point.java
    └── test
        └── java
            └── vu
                └── co
                    └── kspace
                        └── AppTest.java
```

The external libraries tree is showing that binary jars are there, though:

[image]

The only hidden dir is .idea:

```
tree .idea
.idea
├── compiler.xml
├── encodings.xml
├── libraries
│   ├── Maven__com_github_fommil_jniloader_1_1.xml
│   ├── Maven__com_github_fommil_netlib_core_1_1_2.xml
│   ├── Maven__com_github_fommil_netlib_native_ref_java_1_1.xml
│   ├── Maven__com_github_fommil_netlib_native_system_java_1_1.xml
│   ├── Maven__com_github_fommil_netlib_netlib_native_ref_linux_armhf_natives_1_1.xml
│   ├── Maven__com_github_fommil_netlib_netlib_native_ref_linux_i686_natives_1_1.xml
│   ├── Maven__com_github_fommil_netlib_netlib_native_ref_linux_x86_64_natives_1_1.xml
│   ├── Maven__com_github_fommil_netlib_netlib_native_ref_osx_x86_64_natives_1_1.xml
│   ├── Maven__com_github_fommil_netlib_netlib_native_ref_win_i686_natives_1_1.xml
│   ├── Maven__com_github_fommil_netlib_netlib_native_ref_win_x86_64_natives_1_1.xml
│   ├── Maven__com_github_fommil_netlib_netlib_native_system_linux_armhf_natives_1_1.xml
│   ├── Maven__com_github_fommil_netlib_netlib_native_system_linux_i686_natives_1_1.xml
│   ├── Maven__com_github_fommil_netlib_netlib_native_system_linux_x86_64_natives_1_1.xml
│   ├── Maven__com_github_fommil_netlib_netlib_native_system_osx_x86_64_natives_1_1.xml
│   ├── Maven__com_github_fommil_netlib_netlib_native_system_win_i686_natives_1_1.xml
│   ├── Maven__com_github_fommil_netlib_netlib_native_system_win_x86_64_natives_1_1.xml
│   ├── Maven__com_googlecode_matrix_toolkits_java_mtj_1_0_3.xml
│   ├── Maven__junit_junit_3_8_1.xml
│   └── Maven__net_sourceforge_f2j_arpack_combined_all_0_1.xml
├── misc.xml
├── modules.xml
├── vcs.xml
└── workspace.xml

1 directory, 25 files
```

Doc files has clearly been downloaded:

[image]

Comment: The jars reside in the Maven local repository just beside the binary jar as `source` and `javadoc` classifiers. For example: under `~/.m2/repository/com/github/fommil/jniloader/1.1` you may have `jniloader-1.1.jar` `jniloader-1.1-sources.jar` and `jniloader-1.1-javadoc.jar`. This is the Maven way.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the .idea directory inside your project. It will contain a libraries folder with all the maven dependencies listed out in xml files.

For example I have the following:

```
MyProject/.idea/libraries/Maven__org_testng_testng_6_8.xml
```

Which contains:

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="Maven: org.testng:testng:6.8">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$/org/testng/testng/6.8/testng-6.8.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC>
      <root url="jar://$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$/org/testng/testng/6.8/testng-6.8-javadoc.jar!/" />
    </JAVADOC>
    <SOURCES>
      <root url="jar://$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$/org/testng/testng/6.8/testng-6.8-sources.jar!/" />
    </SOURCES>
  </library>
</component>
```

Orid's response was correct. Intellij Idea uses your standard maven repository to store all sources and javadoc jars.

```
$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$ == ~/.m2
```

Comment: It's possible to set the Maven home directory in the settings in IDEA using menu "Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven" or the "tool"-icon on the far left of the "Maven Projects"-tab in the IDE. It seems the default is to use the directory of the bundled maven.